# Is there a way to track the sent email and if the reply is related to that email ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I have setup SES and I do send emails to my clients. and I whenever client responds to my email i push it to a SQS queue and consume these reply emails form my application.

The issue I have now is I have multiple clients in different tenants with the same email so when someone replies to an email I cant identify which client from what tenet is this reply is. I am wondering if its possible for me to attach a unique_id like my client_tenent_id which from that i can find which client and which tenants to the email

or else is it possible for me to identity this response using ses message_id ? like is the message_id same for my sent email and client reply?

please let me know if there's any solution for this problem